# Saber tempo de mouse ocioso

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um sistema de intranet, que os vendedores assistem algumas aulas.

As vezes, eles deixam aberto a janela naquela URL por dias.

O sistema via ajax, tem um contador, então se a pagina ta aberta, ele fica requisitando e gravando no banco que o cara esta online.

Mas como disse, ele pode deixar aberto a janela por dias.

Acho que a melhor forma, seria captar se ele mexeu o mouse.

Então o que eu preciso é, como saber se faz mais de 30 min (por exmeplo) que ele não mexe o mouse.

Com isso, quando passar 30 min sem mexer o mouse, eu posso exibir um dialogo na tela, perguntando, você ainda esta ai? se ele não responder (em até 30 segundos por exemplo), eu deslogo ele.

A minha dúvida seria mesmo, como saber se faz mais de 30 min (por exmeplo) que ele não mexe o mouse

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly

Comment: Show de bola, vou testar. Obrigada :)

Comment: Alguma das respostas solucionou o teu problema?

Answer (score 7):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
var tempoDeEspera = 30 * 60 * 1000;
var timeout = setTimeout(inativo, tempoDeEspera);

function actividade(e) {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(inativo, tempoDeEspera);
  // só para o exemplo
  console.log('Houve actividade de ' + (e.type == 'keyup' ? 'teclado' : 'ponteiro'));
}

function inativo() {
  console.log('Inativo hà mais de 30 minutos...');
}

['keyup', 'touchmove' in window ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove', "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : "DOMMouseScroll"].forEach(function(ev) {
  window.addEventListener(ev, actividade);
});
```

A ideia é apagar o contador em curso e começar um novo cada vez que houver actividade de teclas, mouse ou scroll. Em caso de o contador não ser re-iniciado e chegar ao fim, a função `inativo` é corrida.

Answer (score 0):

> Acho que a melhor forma, seria captar se ele mexeu o mouse.

Respondendo especificamente à pergunta acima, você pode identificar com o seguinte código javascript:

```js
//variável representando o tempo inativo atual
seg = 0;
//Adicionando ao document o evento a ser disparado sempre que o mouse se mover
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){  
  //Caso seja detectado o movimento do mouse, atualizar a variável que representa o tempo de inatividade para 0 segundos
  seg = 0;
});
//A cada 1 segundo (a seu critério), adicionar +1 segundo de tempo de inatividade à variável "seg". Caso tenha chegado a 10 segundos, exibirá um alert.
setInterval(function(){ 
  seg = seg + 1; 
  if(seg == 10)
    alert("Dez segundos inativo.");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Poderia zerar o seg dentro do if

Comment: Vou atualizar o código @Math com uma solução mais próxima da realidade ^^